# g++ option that will retain the value of an unreference variable

Tags: c++

I am having a hard time debugging a code which contains a variable that holds an object. Its value doesn't retain. Like this,

```
//foo.cpp
CCustomClass cfoo = CStaticClass::cfoo_static; // cfoo_static is a static member object

void footest()
{
    // code here that use cfoo but cfoo is empty
}

//main.cpp
int main()
{
   footest();
   return 0;
}
```

Please take note that cfoo is a global in foo.cpp. I'm just wondering if there is an g++ option that will retain the value of a global variable cfoo.

And also please take note that the application will work if I change the cfoo to hold the reference, like this,

```
//foo.cpp
CCustomClass& cfoo = CStaticClass::cfoo_static; // cfoo_static is a static member object
```

But I want to use the first example.

Please advice. Thanks.

Comment: Another question where English seems a better description of the problem than C++

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you might be experiencing the [static initialization order fiasco](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.14). You can solve it with the [construct on first use idiom](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.15). Wrap `cfoo` in a function that initializes the value the first time you call the function. That way, it's guaranteed to be initialized when you need it. Right now, you're getting the value of `cfoo_static` before it has been initialized.

Comment: I see thanks. But is there any other way of "construct on first use idiom" without using a function? Actually the code works fine in another platform with a gcc compiler. But when I port it to another platform using g++ then the problem occurs. So I'm wondering if there is a possible compiler option to work-around this problem.

Comment: No, there isn't. It probably works with on the other platform because the static initialization order is different and it happens to work.

Comment: As the article states, "you have a 50%-50% chance of dying".  Maybe the fact that it works on the other platform is just a matter of luck.  Bad luck, since it makes it seem as though the code is good when it is actually not.

Comment: I see thanks. But I am wondering why it's working if I use the actual static data member in the code and not using a variable.

Comment: @sasayins: When you use the reference, you're aliasing the static data member. So no matter what the initialization order, you're good.

Answer (score 1):

```
//foo.cpp
CCustomClass cfoo = CStaticClass::cfoo_static;
```

Where have you initialized `CStaticClass::cfoo_static`? In a different .cpp?

Please do initialize it in the same file *foo.cpp* **and** before `cfoo`. Something like this:

```
CCustomClass CStaticClass::cfoo_static = //initialization code!
//foo.cpp
CCustomClass cfoo = CStaticClass::cfoo_static;
```

By the way, whatever value you initialize `cfoo_static` with, you can use the same to initialize `cfoo` as well, then why don't you do it, instead of making `cfoo` dependent on `cfoo_static`?

---

## Work Around

If you cannot change your code containing `CStaticClass::cfoo_static`, then maybe this can be useful to you:

```
//foo.cpp
CCustomClass& cfoo() //a function with name cfoo!!
{
    static CCustomClass foo =CStaticClass::cfoo_static;
    return  foo;
}

void footest()
{
   //use cfoo() function!
  
   cfoo().DoWork(); //an example
}
```

Comment: >>Where have you initialized CStaticClass::cfoo_static? In a different .cpp?
yeah in different file, actually its a public header to use. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with the order of initialization of global data.  You can't assume that cfoo_static was initialized before it is assigned to cfoo.

Your best bet is to avoid the over-use of global data.

One way that you could fix this is by performing the assignment inside one of your functions.

Comment: Too bad for me, I don't have any option to change that actual code. Thanks

Comment: Can you change ANY of the code, or are you only looking for a way to fix this with compiler options?

Comment: Yeah I hope there is a compiler option to fix this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you may want to use a singleton desing patten and do something like this:

```
CcustomClass* getFoo(void) {
    static CcustomClass* cfoo = null;
    if (cfoo == null) {
        cfoo = new CcustomClass();
    }
    return cfoo;
}
```

and then call getFoo every time you want to use it.

Comment: This isn't singleton. It is, however, a form of the "construct on first use" idiom. That's the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is a compiler option to fix this -- the problem is the [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in the code itself.

However, you might be able to get it working on a given platform by re-arranging the order in which the files are linked -- *but this is a [kludge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kludge#In_computer_science) of major proportions*.